# Equivalent of Convert.ToChar(byte) in .Net 2.0?

Tags: c#, char, byte, c#-2.0

I'm confined to using only .Net 2.0 and trying to write something that will convert a byte to char.

Ideally I would use `Convert.ToChar(buffer[i]);` to get a char from a `byte` in a `byte[]` array but in .Net 2.0 this feature didn't exist. Using `BitConverter.ToChar(buffer, i)` seems to always result in array out of bounds errors.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I might convert a byte to char in .Net 2.0?

Comment: What characterset will be the bytes be in? ASCII?

Comment: is `buffer[i]` array of byte?. note that `BitConverter.ToChar(buffer, i)` requires two bytes from `buffer` so the start index `i` should be less than `buffer.Length - 1`.

Comment: ascii could have special characters from english, german, french, among other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have a `byte` then you have to assume the character is ASCII.  `char` is Unicode 16.  The 1st 128 code values of ASCII map directly to Unicode. So try this

```
public char ToChar(byte b)
{
  if (b < 0 || b > 127)
     throw new ArgumentException("Not an ASCII character.");
  return (char) b;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Most network software now assumes a string is encoded in UTF-8.  So if you know the number of bytes in the buffer then you should do

```
var s = Encoding.Utf8.GetString(buffer, i, n);
```

Where *n* is the number of bytes.

Comment: But the OP talks about array of `byte`, so they can be from a multibyte charset. But with the assumptions you have defined, your code should work.

Comment: Needs to take into account different languages, such as German with special characters and symbols.

Comment: See my update.  You have to consider what encoding is being used.  If its UTF-8 then languages (special chars and symbols) can be decoded.